# How to spawn every process by a user in a specified network namespace

Tags: linux, hadoop, networking, namespaces, vpn

I've got a network namepsace named ns_hadoop.
I also have a hadoopuser.

I want to spawn all process that are started by that user, whether it be a shell or a cron job, in the ns_hadoop namespace. That way I can basically make only one user connect to the VPN, while the rest keep operating just fine.

How do I go about doing that?

I've been trying to use unshare, and I've looking into changing the shell in /etc/passwd. But to my understanding, both of these solutions don't cover every process

Comment: I don't understand how this is a Hadoop question? Are you asking about YARN (or Oozie for cron)?